# Magento 2 - delete product in shopping cart view - blank page

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

when we delete a product in the shopping cart (checkout/cart/index/) view via the button "Remove item", I always get a blank page at the checkout/cart/delete/ page.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

We are using Magento 2.3.3 - here simply as guest user, not logged in, but for logged in users same happens.

I´d be grateful for any hint.

Comment: Please remove comment in app/bootstrap.php file in this line **ini_set('display_errors', 1);** and check what error you're getting on delete action ?

Comment: Dear Kishan. Thank you very much. Now I get this error message here: https://pasteboard.co/IGFdKqe.jpg It seems some Google Shopping Plugin, but do not know where and what this does. Strange.

Comment: can you please remove generated directory and run setup:upgrade command once and check again ?

Comment: Dear Kishan, we did so, but error remains. We can try to disable this Google Shopping Module possibly?

Comment: Yes, Please try to disable that module and check

Comment: Yeah. Works perfect! Thank you Kishan for all the hints! Great

Comment: You're welcome @Ben :)